# Problem with reputation.

Tags: support, reputation, chat

I'm currently having a problem with my reputation. The chat says it is 2484, but SE shows 2267 which seems to be wrong given the last uptades on the Q&As I've made. Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The rep that shows in Chat is your **total** reputation across the StackExchange network. Seeing that you have also a linked account at Physics and somewhere else, each with around 100 rep, I'd say that that's where the difference comes from.

(For example, my chat display shows almost 26K rep, whereas on Maths I only have arond 17K right now.)

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes, reputation is "out of sync" due to deleted questions or other issues. You can find the most acccurate count by using something like [this link](https://math.stackexchange.com/reputation). At the bottom, once per day, you can trigger a "reputation recalc", which will recompute your reputation to make it current. (You can trigger the recalculation once a day). The reputation syncs up every so often as the site does maintenance anywar.

Comment: Thanks. Since you know about high voted answers: does $X$ upvote stand for $10\times X$ rep. or does the rep. change as upvotes increase? I'm confused since I have one answer with 47 UVs but the rep. timeline seems to show only +205 rep. Maybe that's the problem.

Comment: @Peter: You get 10 points per up-vote, 15 points for acceptance. **However**, there is a daily "cap" on reputation: you cannot gain more than 200 points on upvotes (for questions and for answers) per day; you've already hit the cap a few times (since you have the Mortarboard badge); but that can't be "it", since that wouldn't count in the chat summary either, so you would not show different totals in chat at in the main site. It must be points lost through re-calculation (questions that get deleted where you have answers with up-votes; unaccepted answers, and the like). It happens.

Comment: Ok. That info is very useful. Still, I cant seem to use the link you provide. Rather, it shows calculations on your rep.

Comment: @Peter, did you scroll to the very bottom?

Comment: @Peter: Oh, sorry; there should be a way of getting it to be *your* rep instead of mine. I thought that, since it does not have any user number, it would work for you to give you your rep.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Sorry! It is my data, but as the list starts at 104442 I thought that was rep!

Comment: @Peter: My list starts with the "number of votes". Then it lists my reputation changes per day. The first column is a code indicating the type of reputation change (2 for upvotes; 1 for acceptance bonuses); then the question/answer number; then the reputation points (in parentheses or brackets). 104442 is [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/104383/the-domain-of-integral-of-a-function/104442#104442), which I'm guessing is the first answer where you got an upvote.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Right. Case closed.

Answer (score 1):

This is just to support Willie Wong's answer. Here are your reputations for your various accounts:

[image: rep per account]

which gives a total of 2753.

Here is what chat says you have:

[image: rep per chat]

So the chat total is a bit behind your actual total.